# Publishing a asp .net core 2.1 web app doesn't create runtimes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis, publishing

I have created two .NET Core 2.1 web APIs. The one I made like a year ago publishes correctly:
[Contents of a folder of a working api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVmun.png)

The one I made this week lacks the "runtimes" folder and also has much fewer files:
[Contents of a folder of a non working api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtFWP.png)

I publish the projects into a folder and then copy the files into an appropriate folder on our IIS server.

I can remember that I had problems with publishing year ago with the project that now works, but I can't remember how I made it work. **I am using Visual Studio 2019. Both of these apps are being published in the Release configuration**.
Any ideas?

Comment: VS hides the actual publishing process (`dotnet publish`) from you, so you'd better use command line to learn each of the modes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: Does it work normally when published in debug configuration? how did you publish your .net core web api? you can refer to this link about publish the .net core app [Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

If you use Visual Studio the best way to publish a .NET app is to use the command line like so:

> dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained false

This compiles your app for a x64 architecture with no problems.
The GUI way of publishing is always pretty buggy I've experienced.